# Validation to contain a certain string Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a parameter in one of my models called "facebook_url". How can I be sure the user input contains "facebook.com" and isn't some random website?

Right now I have:

```
unless self.facebook_url[/\Afacebook.com\/\//]
  self.facebook_url = "" unless self.facebook_url == ""
end
```

But this isn't really working how I want it.

Comment: Do you mean the URL exactly is 'facebook.com' or can it be 'mfacebook.com', 'test-facebook.com' etc.?

Comment: As in "facebook.com/blahblahblah". I guess then someone could get passed it by inputing something like "test-facebook.com", but I have no idea how to validate something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regular expression would be:

```
\A((http|https):\/\/)?(www.)?facebook.com\/
```

Will match a string that contains a valid facebook url:

- facebook.com/
- www.facebook.com/
- https://facebook.com/
- https://www.facebook.com/
- http://facebook.com/
- http://www.facebook.com/

Now, to validate your rails model use rails validations on your model file like this:

```
validates :facebook_url, format: { with: /\A((http|https):\/\/)?(www.)?facebook.com\//,
message: "use a valid facebook url" }
```

Using your example code, would be:

```
if self.facebook_url.match(/\A((http|https):\/\/)?(www.)?facebook.com\//)
 # valid facebook url
else
 # invalid facebook url
end
```

You can test the regular expression on [www.rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com)